# View the image, Canvas on Canvas with scroll bar. Throws this error: item configure () is missing 1 required positional argument: 'tagOrId'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas

Can someone help me, I am placing an image on a canvas with vertical and horizontal scroll bars, the images already appear, but it generates the error that I put at the end, I do not see where I am wrong, I do not handle canvas very well.   I have updated my code

```
def visualizar_imagen_consulta(self):
    try:
        self.tree3.item(self.tree3.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        messagebox.showinfo("A T E N C I O N ! ! !", "Selecciones una consulta, por favor!")
        return
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2 = Toplevel()
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.transient(self.windows_consulta1)
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    #self.windows_fichas_consulta2.resizable(0,0)
    #   Medidas del Geometry ("ancho x alto + columna + fila")
    self.windows_fichas_consulta2.geometry("655x600+700+0") #"670x500+10+50"

    query = 'SELECT * FROM visuales WHERE ID_IMAGEN_VISUAL = ?'
    parameters = (self.miid_nombre_imagen.get(), )
    db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)
    for database_visuales2 in db_rows:
        self.midescripcion_imagen.set(database_visuales2[4])

    self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1="/oftica/visuales/" + self.miid_nombre_imagen.get()
    self.tarjeta_imagen_consulta1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1)

    #if self.sw_elimina_imagen==0:
    #frame para menú
    self.frame200 = LabelFrame(self.windows_fichas_consulta2, text = '', foreground = 'darkgreen', font = ('arial', 16, 'bold'), background='lightcyan2')
    self.frame200.place(x=70, y=510) 

    Button(self.frame200, text = ' Escuchar', command = self.voz_imagen_consulta, background="cyan4", 
        image=self.photo_tarjeta_speaker, compound="left", height = 30, width = 150, foreground = 'black', 
        font = ('arial', 12, 'bold')).grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E, pady=5, padx=5)
    Button(self.frame200, text = ' Zoom', command = self.zoom_imagen_consulta2, background="cyan4", 
        image=self.photo_zoom, compound="left", height = 30, width = 150, foreground = 'black', 
        font = ('arial', 12, 'bold')).grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E, pady=5, padx=5)
    Button(self.frame200, text = ' Volver', command = lambda : self.windows_fichas_consulta2.destroy(), background="seaGreen3", 
        image=self.photo_volver_consulta, compound="left", height = 30, width = 150, foreground = 'black', 
        font = ('arial', 12, 'bold')).grid(row = 1, column = 2, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E, pady=5, padx=5)
    Label(self.frame200, text = '' + self.midescripcion_imagen.get(), font = ('arial', 12, 'bold'), 
        background='lightcyan2').grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E, pady=5, padx=5)


    img_frame = tk.Frame(self.windows_fichas_consulta2, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6')
    img_frame.pack()
    canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

    sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    img = Image.open(self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1) 
    width, height = img.size
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    self.image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
    canvas.config(self.image_on_canvas)
```

It shows the image, no problem, but it generates the following error.

```
C:\Oftica>oftalmenu.py
Exception in Tkinter callback  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
   File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 3727, in ver_imagen1
    self.visualizar_imagen_consulta()
   File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 3831, in   visualizar_imagen_consulta
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1631, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 109, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: You need to specify the tag or Id as the error states. The id of canvas items is returned when you create them using `canvas.create_item()`  for example `canvas.create_image()`. So in your case, you might have to pass `image_on_canvas` as the first parameter to `itemconfig`. But I feel like there are many more mistakes you are making besides this.

Comment: The error is saying exactly what is wrong, you must tell it what item you're configuring.

Comment: If I really do not handle canva well as you can see, I will follow your advice and try

Comment: Change `image_on_canvas = canvas.itemconfig(image=image_on_canvas, fill="black")` to `canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill="black")`. Also you need to keep a reference to `img2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I made the change, it continues to generate the image, but it creates a new error for me,

Comment: File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 2667, in visualizar_imagen_consulta
    canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill="black")
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2903, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-fill"

Comment: I'm still stuck with the error, can someone guide me

Comment: canvas.itemconfig(image_on_canvas, fill = 'black'), I have placed this line and now it generates another error, the truth is this has me very confused,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with two changes

First to do Global img2

```
global img2
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

Second changing these lines
self.image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
canvas.config(self.image_on_canvas)

I understood that when using image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image (0, 0, anchor = "nw", image = img2), it returns an int that is used to identify the specific canvas element (its id). For them just change the line to: canvas.create_image (0, 0, anchor = "nw", image = img2)

Mi codigo que de la siguiente manera:

```
    img_frame = tk.Frame(self.windows_fichas_consulta2, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6')
    img_frame.pack()
    canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

    sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
    sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
    sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    global img2
    canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
    canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    img = Image.open(self.tarjeta_ficha_consulta1) 
    width, height = img.size
    canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)
```

Displays the image, scrolls through the horizontal and vertical scroll bars, and no longer generates an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when we use `canvas.itemconfigure` we need to set the tag or the Id of the object that we want to change its options ,then we choose the option that we want to change .In this case , I think that there is no need to use `itemconfigure` since you already create the image you want to create .Also, there no option for `canvas.create_image` called `fill`.

Comment: Ayyoub ESSADEQ, Thanks for helping me, I have removed itemconfigure, and add canvas.config (image_on_canvas), it shows me the image and the scroll bars works, but it gives me another error

Comment: File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 3427, in visualizar_imagen_consulta
    canvas.config(image_on_canvas)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1631, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 109, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: I think that  you tried to calculate the lenght of an integer which is not a admited in python (`object of type 'int' has no len()`) ,but you could convert the `integer` into a `string` then you could calculate it's lenght which means that you want to calculate the number of digits in a number in your case .

Comment: But I don't know if this is what you want ?

Comment: (if you find my answer helpful please admitted as an answer for your problem and thanks) and I'm here if you want any help :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, Ayyoub ESSADEQ, however, it has not worked, what I want is to put the image with canvas and since they are very large, use the scroll bars, according to the code I have I can see the image and the bars work and move the image, but it always generates an error in the command, that's the problem.

Comment: according to the error the problem appears in the line 109 ,but the code that you had already posted doesn't contain that line . So ,if you can share that line I could help you .

Comment: - Ayyoub ESSADEQ, Thank you very much for your help, I have updated the code, line 109 is where I make the call. But I have placed the whole module. The image continues to generate, and the scroll bars work fine, I can move the image horizontally and vertically, only that it generates that error in the command window –